# New Relic: How to set tags automatically, especially when Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, tags, newrelic, autoscaling

When using EC2 autoscaling with New Relic, there will inevitably be a number of servers being started and terminated over time. When using multiple scaling groups, it'd be very useful to have them distinguishable in NR by tags, for example one group could be tagged as "production,workers" and another as "staging,workers" and yet another with the tags "production,api". This can be achieved by manually tagging them in the NR web interface, but that's not practical.

Is there a way to accomplish this automatically, either through `nrsysmond` or a configuration API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use New Relic's Rest API:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/getting-started-with-the-new-relic-rest-api

Comment: That doesn't seem to include tags, you can only rename servers (http://newrelic.github.io/newrelic_api/README_rdoc.html#label-Update+a+server%27s+settings). Same with the API Explorer.

Comment: I know :)  It's time to start yelling at the New Relic guys.

Comment: Here's some dynamic hostname stuff that might be a good starting point:
http://stumblinginthedark.com/aws/newrelic/api/2015/10/09/autoscaling_with_newrelic.html
https://github.com/wtfiwtz/stable-ec2-hostnames